# Capistrano 3 share directory only between some releases

Tags: php, capistrano, composer-php, capistrano3

I am using Capistrano 3 to deploy my PHP application. The PHP dependencies are installed with Composer to the `vendor/` directory. Thing is, the installed dependencies are *almost* always the same. I think only 1 in 30-40 deploys changes the dependencies. I can tell exactly when, because the `composer.lock` file will have changed.

Is it possible with Capistrano 3 to share the `vendor/` directory when the `composer.lock` file has not changed, and to create a new shared one when the file *is* changed?